# How do I make a dropdown in Firefox look the same as Chrome/IE?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

So, I'm building a website with a dropdown menu. In `Chrome` it looks nice, but on `Firefox` it takes no padding and I would like to find a way to make them look the same on the both browsers.

I'm aware that this is a known issue, but I didn't find a decent fix for my problem.

Here's a drawing from the dropdown

[image]

Code on debug

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="MainMenu_nav">
   <ul class="navbar-nav nav h>
      <li aria-haspopup="true" class="HasItems hover focus">
         <div class="Wrapper" tabindex="-1">
              ....
          </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

Css

```
.navbar-collapse{
   max-height:none;
   margin-left:-10px;
   margin-right:-10px;
}

.h{
    position:relative;
    back-ground-color:black;
    margin-left:5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

.h>li.hover{
     background-color:white;
     top:3px
}
.h>li{
   position:Relative;
   white-space:nowrap;
   display:table-cell;
   float:none;
   vertical-align:middle
}
```

What's the trick to apply here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny thing, I guessed this problem might not had anythingto do with the dropdown, but to the fact that firefox somehow ignored the padding.
Seems like I was wrong, since according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980916/firefox-ignores-vertical-margins-on-flex-items-children-of-a-flexbox-unless-ex), this is a bug of Chrome and not Firefox

I've fixed the problem with simply displaying the `li` as block

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
     .h >li.hover{
         height:45px;
         display:block;
         top:3px;
     }
}
```